# The program doesn't seem to be saving the input data correctly (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, typedef

So, I want my program to read data from a file, and save it into different quarter1, quarter2,quarter3, quarter4 depending of it's date, but it doesn't seem to work properly and still don't know why, I've been trying to debug and I'm pretty sure it fails when saving at `saveQuarters` or `existeix` which is basically a dichothomic search which returns if the code exists and if it exists, it returns the position. This is the code:

Comment: You should post a reduced, minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

I just skimmed through some of the stuff you had so this suggestion may not work, but you can try declaring your file as input or output. Perhaps that could be the problem.

Some thing like:

```
string fileName = "data.txt";
ifstream dataFile;
dataFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
```

Comment: that's not the problem, the problem is when I try to save the data into an array

Comment: Is the columns in your data file separated as statename, code and population?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
fitxerCens >> taulaCens[i].stateName;
```

Will grab an entire line of the data file until it sees a space is correct.

Comment: By doing that I get all the text until it detects an empty space, but I mean, I've debugged it, and It reads perfectly the information from the file, I've tried writing couts in the readShipment doing cout << aux.code << endl; and so, but the problem comes when i try to insert that information into every quarter

Comment: @magalenyo Well shit, now i'm running out of ideas to try. When you pass a quarters reference to the saveQuarter function, have you tried de-referencing it?

Comment: Yeah, and still the same bro :(